# how to clean/preprocess this image for tesseract ocr?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

[image: This is the image]

How can i preproces this image for better tesseract ocr prediction? so far i have resized and passed to tesseract-ocr but many similar pics are not giving accurate predictions because of border lines around the licence plate.

Comment: did you try thresholding? Also if the border lines are there for every image we can try cropping the image.

Comment: @Beginner yeah i did thresholding thats not making it prediction better

Comment: I've notice a couple of things that Tesseract doesn't seem to like that apply to this image: 1) frames or boxes around text. if you can get rid of the frame, that will improve recognition 2) margins that are too small. when there is very little space between the letters and the edge of the image, recognition suffers. fix by making the picture bigger with white space around the edges.